# does CiviCRM have the capability to handle approx. 70 pieces of data per customer?

Tags: custom-fields, civireport

I am a contractor working for the Department of Tourism in Vanuatu and we are looking at purchasing CiviCRM.  We are also in the process of developing our first ever comprehensive survey for the 1,000 tourism business we have in Vanuatu, that will drive our strategic planning and development in the future.   The survey will have approx. 70 questions, the majority quantitative and the remainder qualitative. My question would be, does CiviCRM have the capability to handle approx. 70 pieces of data per customer?  And if so can it then be easily analysed for reporting? Can comparisons be made for example….  How many island bungalows  (customer type) have electricity and how many have solar power?

Comment: Just a point. CiviCRM is free open source software. You were probably just using shorthand for 'we are paying someone to help us set this up' but am clarifying that for other readers as much as for you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Kia ora Mary. There are many civi instances with much broader data sets than  you are describing so there is no reason to think civi won't 'handle' the data. In terms of 'comparison' there are a range of searching/reporting capabilities with civicrm and also within Drupal if that is the CMS that could be used for this.

Comment: apologies if  you saw 'mark' not 'mary' - not sure if i went cross-eyed or just mistyped

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to create and administer the survey in CiviCRM, and various ways to analyze and report the results. You likely want to use the misnamed CiviPetition functionality (not CiviSurvey, since that is for cases where you have many staff people posing questions and recording responses to their own batch of respondents that they have reserved for themselves in the system). Or, if you are using CiviCRM with Drupal then you can make the online survey look nicer using the Webform CiviCRM module in Drupal. The reporting questions you pose are quite simple and can be done either in CiviCRM or using Drupal views. More complex ones like crosstab reports might require a bit more work to find a way to produce it, for example using the extended report extension in CiviCRM (from @petednz's company, Fuzion, based in NZ) or a custom report or using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_crosstab in Drupal.

Comment: Good points. Extended Report extension also has some capacity for Pivot Tables